# Iterating a suffix using apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the apply function in Pandas with a lambda to create a named value.

I have the `TIME` column and I want the `ACT_NUM` column as shown in the following.

```
df
TIME    ACT_NUM
3       act_1
3       act_1
4       act_1
12      act_2
3       act_2
15      act_3
```

The logic of the wanted column: When the value in the TIME column is > 10, then I would like to **increment** the suffix number by 1 **permanently**.

I have tried this, but it was not working because I couldn't integrate the variable `n` row to row when using `apply`.

```
n = 1
df['ACT_NUM'] = df['TIME'].apply(lambda x: 'act_'+(n+1) if x>10 else 'act_'+n)
```

Comment: @BillHuang. The expected output is the column 'ACT_NUM'.  Sorry about the mess, I just cleaned this up.  I'm really new on this site and don't have a good way of displaying a dataframe

Comment: The format is OK. But may you edit the post to show what you have and what you want? In addition, IIRC, shouldn't the last row be `15  act_3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[df.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) on `df["TIME"] > 10` seems to be what you are looking for. The cumsum begins from 0 and increase by 1 whenever a row with `df["TIME"] > 10` is encountered.

**Code**

```
df["ACT_NUM"] = (df["TIME"] > 10).cumsum().apply(lambda el: f"act_{el + 1}")
```

**Result**

```
print(df)
   TIME ACT_NUM
0     3   act_1
1     3   act_1
2     4   act_1
3    12   act_2
4     3   act_2
5    15   act_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str(n+1)` and `str(n)` to convert number to string :

```
df['ACT_NUM'] = df['TIME'].apply(lambda x: 'act_'+str(n+1) if x>10 else 'act_'+str(n))
```